# how to see change a new created file permissions in android?

Tags: java, android, operating-system, filesystems

I create a new imageFile in my android storage.

I want to see its r/w/e permissions via the adb shell.

If permissions are not sufficient, how can I change the file permissions to

read all, write by all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the file permission attribute through `adb shell ls -l /path/to/file/name`. Usually you use `chmod`  to change file permission (`chmod 666 file` to give read/write access to the file). Of course, to change it, your user should be the owner of the file (or should belongs to the group). For instance, if you use  `touch`   to create a file on the `sdcard`,   he assign `root` as user and `sdcard_r` as group, making impossible to change its permission if you do not have root access.